# On an inbound email need to create a record dynamically in some cutsom module sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I am able to create a case successfully on an inbound email for a group account by enable Enable "Create Case from Email" in advance set up,

Instead of create a case, i want to create a record in custom module for this where can i write code? 
I am using CE 6.5.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create an after save logic hook on the Email module where the other record can be created. Then the function for "Create Case from Email" can be left unchecked.

Comment: Is there way to import emails from a shared folder(public folder emails) to sugarcrm? If so can  you people guide me how can i achieve this?   thanks.. Naren.